# My Nvidia GeForce 940MX doesn't have OpenGL?

Tags: windows-10, opengl

I'm having a problem with my graphics card's driver. It doesn't seem to have OpenGL support...

If I download OpenGL Extensions Viewer, my card doesn't show up, it's just my Onboard Intel that has the OpenGL acceleration and there is one that shows "GDI Generic". Nvidia page says that my card supports OpenGL 4.5, but it's not working... I need OpenGL acceleration to work with my graphics card for it to be the renderer in some of my programs.

Drivers for the card are updated so I don't understand...

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have optimus switching in your device. In Geforce driver settings, enable High Performance for the OpenGL Viewer exe

Comment: Should I just change my GPU to be the default to fix everything then?

Comment: set all programs that need OpenGL to High performance. otherwise the nVIDIA would be always used and this would cause more heat and less time to work on battery

Answer (score 1):

According to this [NVidia Manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf), you will need force rendering mode for Integrated Graphics or High-Performance Graphics. So, go to PC graphics configuration and force rendering, and after that go to OpenGL Extensions Viewer and the card will appear:

[image: OpenGL Extensions Viewer]

P.S. I have a notebook with a NVIDIA 4.5 specification, but the integrated card shows only 4.4. 
I think this is because the integrated card has only some 4.5 resources.